# Can you kill event listeners in a content script that listen to underlying page events?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome Extension that, in a content script, listens for specific events on the page it is injected into.

The listeners are created on a focusin event - because the elements I want to listen for only exist in certain situations.

Everything works great...except every time the user focusins (understandably) new listeners are created. So I end up with many duplicate events.

My Extension works with very specific pages, so I know whether they have Jquery or not...this one does.

In the focusin listener I have:

```
 $('.PageClass_I_listen_for').blur(function(){
  console.log('blurred out of comment area...');
  //Do something
 });
```

I've tried including 'off' commands at the start of the focusin listener - to kill any existing event listeners before adding a new one. The following code does not have any effect:

```
$(document).off('click', '.PageClass_I_listen_for');  //  Kill events
```

Perhaps you cannot kill events (understandably) that are part of a page into which your code is injected?

Any way to get around this?

Help appreciated!

Comment: You're not using `off` correctly, you've added a `blur` event listener and you're trying to remove a `click` event listener. Here is the [DOCUMENTATION for `jQuery.off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Comment: This is an extension-specific task. Since the content script runs in *isolated world* you need to run the `off` code [in page context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879) to use jQuery of the page, as opposed to jQuery of your content script.

Comment: @wOxxOm, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than attach event listeners directly to elements, I strongly you use event delegation.

Basically, you attach a single event listener somewhere in the hierarchy above the element you're interested in.  Then, it doesn't matter if elements are added or removed dynamically later on.

```
$(document).on( 'blur', '.PageClass_I_listen_for', function( e ) {
  // use e.currentTarget here
} );
```

Your code for `.off` doesn't work because you are not removing from the same elements you are adding the events to, nor are you removing the same *type* of event.  You added the event directly to the elements, but you removing events delegated to `document`.

See: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Thank you for the comments and help...I just didn't connect using a document-level even listener in a Chrome content page. Total mind block and lack of understanding the basic mental model for me...but this did the trick and the nightmare appears to be over...:)